# timeout is not being taken into consideration using axis1.4

Tags: java, axis

I'm setting the timeout when initializing the webservice stub and I'm even logging it using getTimeout() before making the call to make sure it's set but the call completes regardless of the timeout value set. Is it possible this is a bug or am I missing something here?

Below is my code doing this:

```
proxy = new DCPControllerWSPortTypeProxy();
proxy.setEndpoint(endpoint);            
((Stub)proxy.getDCPControllerWSPortType()).setTimeout(120000);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix the problem, you will have to add the following class wherever you want in your project. When I had a similar problem, I have declared it as a private class in the same class where I'm instantiating my stub. (I'm currently using Axis 2 )

```
private class CustomNetworkClient extends sun.net.NetworkClient
{
    
    public CustomNetworkClient(int readTimeout)
    {
        defaultSoTimeout = readTimeout;
        
    }
    
}
```

After doing that, you could add the following line in your code, which will set the timeout.

```
CustomNetworkClient client = new CustomNetworkClient(SOAP_READ_TIMEOUT);
```

Or you could simply do the following, since you don't really need the object that's being created:

```
new CustomNetworkClient(SOAP_READ_TIMEOUT)
```

This has been reported as a bug before, where connection timeouts and read timeouts are not being set when using HTTPS connections : https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4700777

The following link helped me figure out this workaround:
http://www.noizeramp.com/article.php?article=se-networking_specifics_under_Java_Web_Start

I hope this will help you somehow =)